# How to avoid DefaultMessageListenerContainer from automatically starting?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

A Spring `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` starts immediately listening to JMS Destination once I do a XML Load application context.

How can I avoid `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` start listening immediately?

I want to start it manually after loading the context by: `(... ctx.getBean(..)).start();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [autoStartup](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractJmsListeningContainer.html#setAutoStartup(boolean)) property to decide whether the container should be started at startup or not.

> `public void setAutoStartup(boolean autoStartup)`
>    Set whether to automatically start the container after initialization.
>   Default is "true"; set this to "false" to allow for manual startup
>   through the start() method.

Answer (score 1):

Set its `autoStartup` property to `false`.

It's not available when using the `<jms:...>` namespace, but it's there if you define the container using `<bean/>` or `@Bean`.

Comment: Hi Gary , I have similar issue i need to use the method setAutoStartup() to have control on my jms listener container but i am using <jms:../> namespace. I am trying to make as <bean/> but in my existing configurations, error handler have been used. Could you help on how to handle it.

Comment: Don't comment on 2 year old answers with a new question; ask a completely new question and show your old/new configuration.